# Connect to different VPC inside of Kubernetes pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, containers, amazon-elb, kops

I have two VPCs, `VPC A` and `VPC B` . I have one service running in `VPC B`. Kubernetes cluster is in `VPC A`. I am using KOPS in AWS cloud and VPC peering enabled between two VPCs. I can connect to the service running in `VPC B` from the Kubernetes deployment server host in `VPC A`. But, I can not connect to the service inside the Kubernetes pod. It is giving timed out. I searched on internet and I found that IPTABLE rules could work. 
I have gone through this article, 
https://ben.straub.cc/2015/08/19/kubernetes-aws-vpc-peering/

But it is not possible to manually ssh into Kubernetes node servers and set the IPTABLE rules. I want to add it as a part of `deployment`.

This is my service looks like,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-microservice
  namespace: development
spec:
#  type: LoadBalancer
  type: NodePort
 # clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: test-microservice
```

Comment: How did you expose the service out of kubernetes? Is it of type NodePort or LoadBalancer ?

Comment: I am using type NodePort, I have updated the question with my service. Please check

Comment: This sounds like you need to majorly rethink your network architecture? The kops default is "kubenet" i.e. manually created AWS routing tables such that you would have to add the VPC peering route into that table.

Comment: What CNI plugin are you using?